# ndk build error for tessract

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am totally new to tessract.I have successfully completed the following steps,

```
cd <project-directory>
curl -O https://tesseract-ocr.googlecode.com/files/tesseract-ocr-3.02.02.tar.gz
curl -O http://leptonica.googlecode.com/files/leptonica-1.69.tar.gz
tar -zxvf tesseract-ocr-3.02.02.tar.gz
tar -zxvf leptonica-1.69.tar.gz
rm -f tesseract-ocr-3.02.02.tar.gz
rm -f leptonica-1.69.tar.gz
mv tesseract-3.02.02 jni/com_googlecode_tesseract_android/src
mv leptonica-1.69 jni/com_googlecode_leptonica_android/src
```

But when i run the next step which is,

ndk-build -j8

it shows me following errors,

```
[armeabi] SharedLibrary  : liblept.so
[armeabi-v7a] SharedLibrary  : liblept.so
[x86] SharedLibrary  : liblept.so
[mips] SharedLibrary  : liblept.so
jni/com_googlecode_leptonica_android/stdio/open_memstream.c:188: error: undefined reference to '__sfp'
jni/com_googlecode_leptonica_android/stdio/fopencookie.c:154: error: undefined reference to '__sflags'
jni/com_googlecode_leptonica_android/stdio/fopencookie.c:161: error: undefined reference to '__sfp'
jni/com_googlecode_leptonica_android/stdio/fmemopen.c:209: error: undefined reference to '__sflags'
jni/com_googlecode_leptonica_android/stdio/fmemopen.c:215: error: undefined reference to '__sfp'
jni/com_googlecode_leptonica_android/stdio/fmemopen.c:215: error: undefined reference to '__sfp'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [obj/local/x86/liblept.so] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

Comment: you forgot to show the errors

Comment: srry, knw i have shown, can you lease help me out @RishabhLashkari

Comment: I have recently made an an app which uses tessract, but I am working on windows. There is a good tutorial for it. If you want i can give you the link. Sorry was not able to help.

Comment: ok .please share me the link @RishabhLashkari

Comment: https://coderwall.com/p/eurvaq/tesseract-with-andoird-and-gradle Try this may help

Comment: I followed the steps in this link. It might help

http://androidadvance.com/blog/tutorial-getting-started-with-tessaract-ocr-in-android-android-studio/